# os.path.abspath doen't return the correct path

Tags: python

It doesn't behave in the way I except:

```
def main():
    print(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1]))
    print(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
```

the output of this code is:

> /cs/my_user/wanted_path
>
> /cs/my_user/Desktop/project

Actually it just skipped two folders behind my current working directory.

Comment: this belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: An absolute path depends on your current working directory, not the directory that the calling module is in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the absolute path with [`abspath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath)

```
def main():
    filename = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1])
```

This will convert a relative path to an absolute path while leaving an already absolute path unchanged.

Comment: I tried this, but in very strange way it doesn't keep the last folder (when python script and the arg path in the same folder)

Comment: @SuperMario provide an example of your problem, bearing in mind that a "relative" path is generally defined to be relative to the working directory, not your script.  Are you wanting to do the latter?